# Java string format to c# string format

Tags: java, c#, string, string-formatting

Hi is there a way to convert the java string format to c#? I want to code in c# but I don't know how I can translate this java CODE:

```
String credentials = String.format("%s:%s", param1, param2);
```

I have already tried to translate it to c# but it doesn't work for me here is my c# code:

```
string credentials = string.Format("%s:%s", param1, param2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string interpolation (more at [$ - string interpolation (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)):

```
string credentials = $"{param1}:{param2}";
```

Otherwise it's composite formatting with indexes (see [Composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting)):

```
string.Format("{0}:{1}", param1, param2);
```

Comment: or just `string credentials = param1 + ":" + param2;`